# Jetty HttpChannel timeout error for embedded video in web page

Tags: spring-mvc, jetty, video-streaming, html5-video, spring-boot

I have an embedded video playing in the background of a web page, pretty much like how it is in `www.airbnb.com`

```
  <div class="fullwidthbanner">
    <video id="#myvideo" loop="loop" muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay">
      <source th:src="@{/videos/cignme.mp4}" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </div>
```

However after an initial play of may 10 seconds or so, the video blacks out and page goes unresponsive, and I see the following logs

```
2015-03-28 17:17:33.854  WARN 5109 --- [tp1590404373-40] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel     : /videos/cignme.mp4

java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30002/30000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.block(SharedBlockingCallback.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:347)
    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.writeContent(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:407)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:240)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30002/30000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 common frames omitted

2015-03-28 17:17:33.856  WARN 5109 --- [tp1590404373-40] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel     : Could not send response error 500: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30002/30000 ms
```

I am using `Callable` for asynchronous request for the home page, but that's about it, a call to the root context "/" is returned with home page without any other operations which has amongst other things this embedded video.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

  @Resource
  private Environment environment;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
  public Callable<String> home() {
    return new Callable<String>() {

      @Override
      public String call() throws Exception {
        return "home-new";
      }
    };
  }
```

Do I have to implement a RTSP or RTMP for this? Or Am I missing configuration or annotation that could take care of, making timeout 0 for all URLs under path `/videos/` ?

In production I will be using Cloudfront to serve this video, so is it more of a problem for my local setup?